# How do i put 3 conditions into an if statement. on must be true, then one of the next two must be true

Tags: java

I'm trying to put 3 conditions into an if statement but am stuck. 
Its a piece of a program where i am required to find out if the year entered in the JOptionPane is a leap year. to be true "the number in variable iYear must be divible by 4. It must also be divisible by one either 100 or 400 to be true.

Heres what i have right now but outputs are coming back false even on leap years so i must be coding something wrong.

```
if ((iYear % 4 == 0) && (iYear % 100 == 0) || (iYear % 400 == 0){
    blnLeapYear = true;
} else {
    blnLeapYear = false;
}
```

Comment: 100 and 400 is %4 ==0 already you dont need 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have written here is wrong condition for leap year.
It should be

```
if ((iYear % 4 == 0) && (iYear % 100 != 0) || (iYear % 400 == 0)

    {
        blnLeapYear = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        blnLeapYear = false;
    }
```

**Leap years are years divisible by 4 but not 100 or divisible by 400**.
Therefore, 100, 200, 300 are non leap years but 400 is a leap year.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 8, then use :

```
java.time.Year.of(iYear).isLeap()
```

Java implementation of above method:

```
public static boolean isLeap(long year) {
        return ((year & 3) == 0) && ((year % 100) != 0 || (year % 400) == 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*400 dividible by 100* so any **400x** will be `x % 100 == 0:`

So since you said 400 or 100 we can safely pick 100 and disregard 400.

*100 is dividible by 4* in this case any **100x** will be `x % 100 == 0`

Which left us:

```
   if(iYear % 100 == 0){
    ...
```

**edited